# Call method in proxy child model from parent instance

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm developing an application in Django (python framework, v1.7).

I need to "append" a method to the django User model, so that when i instance a user (i.e. logging in) i can call that method and get results directly in the user object i've just instanced.

I used a trick call "monkey-patching", that works like this:

```
def my_method(self):

    # do something...

# Appending method to User class
User.add_to_class("my_method", my_method)
```

To make this working, i imported the file containing the code above in `__init__.py` situated in the same folder of `__settings.py`. This way, when the server runs, my method will be imported and appended to the user class.

Unfortunately, i found some problems when i need to perform queries or other operations by terminal (or scripts) and not using Django Admin. Debugging code, i understood it is an import problem.

Browsing Django Documentation i found another way to append a method to the user class, creating a proxy modeld from User. Look at the paragraph "Extending the existing User model" in [this page](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.x/topics/auth/customizing.html).
As a result, this is the new proxy model i created:

```
class UserPatch(User):

    def my_method(self):

        # do something...

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Now my method should be appended to the user class, but i can't find a way to access to it. I would perform something like `User.my_method()` but of course is not possible, since `my_method()` is not really a method of the class User.

I'm sure it is possible to get the child model instance from the parent model, as specified here:

> instances of Person will also be accessible through MyPerson, and
>   vice-versa
>
> Quote form [this documentation](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.x/topics/db/models.html#proxy-models)

Do you have any idea of how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess. You wanted to access a child model's method from request.user?

> instances of Person will also be accessible through MyPerson, and
>   vice-versa

It's a bit messing statement. Look through proxy models documentation. That 'vice-versa' is true only for instance data (fields and their content), but not for child model's methods.
To access such methods from request.user instance you should define your custom user model with those methods as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: Thank you pythonpro. However i opted for a different solution, using the user's session which contains the user's info, indeed. This way i got some advantages for my app.